# how to pass a super class as a parameter

Tags: java

i have multiple classes all extending some vendor provided class e.g.

```
class A extends vendor.A 
class B extends vendor.B 
class  C extends vendor.C
```

now currently all of the custom classes have a method isValidLoad() that invokes vendor super class method isValidLoad() method. This super isValidLoad() is invoked as long as some conditions are true.

I want to club this common lines in a separate class ,and all the custom classes must invoke this common method.

My challenge is how to pass the super class(e.g vendor.A,vendor.B,vendor.C etc as parameter so that the common code can invoke the super class method isValidLoad method

Comment: pass a `java.util.function.Supplier` to your club method !